# HNQ list in stackexchange.com tooltips request

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, hot-questions, tooltips

## tl;dr:

Can we please get the following tooltips in the HNQ list?

1. user's reputation when hovering over the user's name
2. Some indication of the question's score
3. time stamp of question posting when hovering over "asked X hours ago".
4. actual site name, and not url, when hovering over site icon\name

The [HNQ list on stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) doesn't have tooltips (apart from the arbitrary points and the "visit this question on SiteName"). Can some tooltips be added?

Even the "asked X hours ago", which across the network usually has a tooltip for the exact timestamp, is tooltipless.

Also, users' display names usually show their reputation points on hover (I think this might be more complicated, because it would mean fetching their rep on the specified site, but maybe not).

And, it'd be nice to see some indication of the score of the question (the upvotes minus downvotes score; not the arbitrary hotness)

[image: freehand, just for you]

<sub>(you might want to hover over the image)</sub>

So, can these tooltips be added, for the sake of consistency?
(at least the timestamp. I was really looking forward to a whole bunch of interesting stats, only to discover that there was no tooltip).

### EDIT

Regarding the site's icon tooltip: it says "view this question on `[site url]`".
Literally the url: (the math one in the picture says math.stackexchange.com)

So, is the `.com` needed? maybe just entering the name that `[math.se]` expands into...

### EDIT 2

After looking at the [real time tab](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=realtime), I saw that the "top network sites" listed in the sidebar have a tooltip with the site name and description (i.e Stack Overflow has "Stack Overflow - Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers").

So if the page already has the names of all sites (or at least it *can* show the name and description for the network's sites), then I suppose it isn't a total do-over to add the tooltips to the sites' icons in the Hot tab.