# Add tooltip with timestamp to Hot Network Questions list

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, hot-questions, tooltips, timestamps

Almost all dates (absolute, like 'Aug 8 '17 at 11:12', and relative, like '12 hours ago') on Stack Exchange can be hovered over to see the exact UTC timestamp. I found an instance where this is not the case: the list of Hot Network Questions on the [Stack Exchange homepage](https://stackexchange.com/):

[image]

I expect that when I hover over the 'asked 2 days ago', a tooltip will tell me exactly when that was. Can it be added please, if only for consistency's sake?

Comment: It's part of [this broader feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299532/hnq-list-in-stackexchange-com-tooltips-request).

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks, don't know how I missed that in my search. That one is rather broad, I hope they're more inclined to make a small improvement.