# Add tooltip with exact timestamp to 'Data updated ... ago' label on SEDE homepage

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, dates

Can we add a tooltip with the exact UTC timestamp to the 'Data updated ... ago' label on the SEDE homepage? It would help indicating whether the refresh was slow (as it was today) or even incomplete. And it would be consistent with ([almost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350074/295232)) all (relative and absolute) date/time indications on Stack Exchange, and the timestamps on user flairs on query pages already have such tooltips.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, can be null as well so might need some extra care but it should go here: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/blob/master/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Views/Home/Index.cshtml#L6